# Android add view in status bar

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

This is my code for adding view:

```
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    TextView tv = (TextView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.textview, null);
    final View view = tv;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 25,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_STATUS_BAR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SCALED
            , PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(view, lp);
```

but it's will give me an error:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41668948 -- permission denied for this window type

so i add permission in android manifast

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR" />
```

but still error is there, i need help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code snippet, it like you're trying to create a new *status bar window,* which is not possible. (There is one status bar and it is managed by the System UI.)

Can you describe what you're trying to do? In general you interact with the status bar using the [Notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) and [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) APIs.

Answer (score 4):

In order to draw views on top of the status bar, this is the combinations that worked for me after reading so many stack overflow post:

1- You need to have WindowManager of this LayoutParameters on either your service or your activity:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    statusBarHeight, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |       
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

2- You just need this permission on your android manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"
```

Hope that helps. In my case I just needed to tint the statusbar with a tranluscent yellow or green to indicate that user is currently in an active call

Comment: great, but the clicks are not enabled on this window manager, i tried changing the flags but i cant make it listen to the clicks (it was working fine before with different flags), is there a solution for that ... im displaying custom toasts in this area

Answer (score 0):

ok this should work:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Comment: do you have any other idea what is the problem might be?

Comment: Could you maybe include a stack trace